Focusing on an element of a subset, of a subset
Fairly new to coding and I have a question regarding list and subsets.
Suppose this is my list:
list =
[[[a,2], [c,3], [e,3]],
[[g,4], [i,4] [k,3]],
[[b,3], [d,2], [f,2]]]

How would I go about making a new list that focuses on index -1 (or the numbers) to add them up and if the sum is more than 8 to not print into new list and if it's less have it print.
For example:
[a,2], [c,3],[e,3] sum is 8 so it would print
[g,4],[i,4],[k,3] sum is 11 so it would not print
[b,3], [d,2], [f,2] sum is 7 so it would print
Also this list would be bigger so I'm thinking maybe a loop but no idea, any suggestions will help thank you
new_list = []
i = 0
while i < 10:
    if (list[i][0][-1] + list[i][1][-1] + list[i][2][2] < 8)
    print (list[i] in new_list) #dont think this is right
    i = i + 1
return

I thought this would loop again but got 3 lines of false

A few tips on your code: Don't use list as a variable name because it is a  built in function. Also your first code snippet doesn't execute for 2 reasons. To split a statement over multiple lines use the \ character.  You didn't define a, b, ... etc.  Are these variables or did you mean strings like 'a', 'b', ...?  Hope that helps.

You can do it as a pythonic 1-liner like below:
xss = [
    [['a', 2], ['c', 3], ['e', 3]],
    [['g', 4], ['i', 4], ['k', 3]],
    [['b', 3], ['d', 2], ['f', 2]],
]


yss = [xs for xs in xss if sum(x[-1] for x in xs) <= 8]
print(yss)


You can do this very succinctly by making a simple generator expression to sum the row. Then print the one you want:
list_a =[
    [["a",2], ["c",3], ["e",3]],
    [["g",4], ["i",4], ["k",3]],
    [["b",3], ["d",2], ["f",2]]
]

# a generator to generate the sums of each row's last elements
row_sums = (sum(j[-1] for j in i) for i in list_a)

# selectively print them with a newline between them
print(*(sum for sum in row_sums if sum <= 8), sep="\n")

This will print:
8
7


Check This
my_list = [[['a', 2], ['c', 3], ['e', 3]],
           [['g', 4], ['i', 4], ['k', 3]],
           [['b', 3], ['d', 2], ['f', 2]]]

filter_data = []

for inner_list in my_list:
    # Calculate the sum of the second elements (index -1)
    total = sum(item[1] for item in inner_list)

    # Check if the sum is less than or equal to 8
    if total <= 8:
        print(f'Inner List : {inner_list} and total: {total}')
        filter_data.append(inner_list)
    else:
        print(f'Inner List : {inner_list} and total: {total}')
print(f'\n Final filter output:{filter_data} ')


It will print like this :
Inner List : [['a', 2], ['c', 3], ['e', 3]] and total: 8
Inner List : [['g', 4], ['i', 4], ['k', 3]] and total: 11
Inner List : [['b', 3], ['d', 2], ['f', 2]] and total: 7
Final filter output:[[['a', 2], ['c', 3], ['e', 3]], [['b', 3], ['d', 2], ['f', 2]]]

This is how you can calculate sum of each row having multiple list of char and int.
list_a =[
    [["a",2], ["c",3], ["e",3]],
    [["g",4], ["i",4], ["k",3]],
    [["b",3], ["d",2], ["f",2]]
]
#Iterating over row
for row in list_a:
    # Initializing sum with zero  before calculating sum for each row
    sum_of_row = 0
    # Iterating over cells in row
    for cell in row:
        # Here cell[0] is string and cell[1] is int
        sum_of_row = sum_of_row + cell[1]
    if sum_of_row > 8:
        print(sum_of_row)
        


In keeping with the Zen of Python and therefore not writing convoluted / hard to understand and unnecessary one-liners I propose:
_list = [[[0, 2], [0, 3], [0, 3]], [[0, 4], [0, 4], [0, 3]], [[0, 3], [0, 2], [0, 2]]]

for e in _list:
    if sum(_e[-1] for _e in e) <= 8:
        print(e)

Output:
[[0, 2], [0, 3], [0, 3]]
[[0, 3], [0, 2], [0, 2]]

